# How do I add watermark programmatically?

Tags: php, image, magento-1.6

I don't if it is possible to add watermark to product images programmatically. Here is my situation:

On the category pages and the product details pages, I want to show the product images WITHOUT watermarks. However, we have a function that a customer can add some of the products to their favorites, and we can send an email to the customer along with their favorite product images. Within the email, I want all the product images to be watermarked.

If I setup the watermark in Magento Admin, the product images on category pages will have watermarks, which is not what I want. Can Magento do some magic like `$product->getWatermarkedImageUrl()` when I want to watermark images?

I am using Magento 1.6.1.0 Community version.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have separate images with watermarks already on the image?  Or do you want to somehow use php to inject watermarks onto images?

Comment: Well, having separate images is the last thing I will do. I am trying to avoid that if I can do something in magento. And using php looks like the same option with having separate images. Basically, what I want is to save the watermarked images automatically into magento media (cached images) and can retrieve the url, just like the normal product images. I am just wondering if magento can do some magic, if not, I have  some other solutions.

Comment: I wasn't aware that magento was capable of this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually create the watermark image and store them in a separate folder, then use the url to these images in your email

See [Magento: Create Watermark Image](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-create-watermark-image/)

```
// update with  path to product image
$mainImage = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'test' . DS . 'image.jpg';

//update with path to watermark
$watermarkImage = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'test' . DS . 'watermark.jpg';

$image = new Varien_Image($mainImage);

// set watermark image width
$image->setWatermarkWidth(100);

// set watermark image height
$image->setWatermarkHeigth(100);

// create watermark image
// watermark($watermarkImage, $positionX=0, $positionY=0, $watermarkImageOpacity=30, $repeat=false)
$image->watermark($watermarkImage);

// save the watermark image
$image->save(Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'test' . DS . 'new.jpg');
```

Comment: It looks like that's the easiest way to do. Thanks.

Comment: FYI this did not work for me without adding the following line:

`$image->setWatermarkImageOpacity(30);`