# How i do watermark programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, catalog, image

I have a code that runs on 'catalog_block_product_list_collection' event. I need add to product image watermark. How i can do it?

```
public function addLabel($collection)
{ 
    $event = $collection->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $label = Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->load(13)->getData();
    $file = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $label['product_page_image'];

    foreach ($event as $product) {
        $product->getCollection();
        $product->setWatermark($file, 25, 0, 200, 200, 50);
    }   


    return $collection->getEvent()->setCollection($event);
}
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46489/20064)

Comment: It is not wokring

Comment: It is output empty product page